# How to regexp match surrounding whitespace or beginning/end of line

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I am trying to find lines in a file that contain a `/` (slash) character which is not part of a word, like this:

```
grep "\</\>" file
```

But no luck, even if the file contains the "/" alone, `grep` does not find it.

I want to be able to match lines such as

```
some text / pictures
/ text
text /
```

but *not* e.g.

```
/home
```

Comment: Do you want `slash` surrounded by `spaces`?

Comment: no, `slash` surrouned by any white character even the beggining or end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why your approach does not work**

`\<`, `\>` only match against the beginning (or end, respectively) of a *word*.  That means that they can *never* match if put adjacent to `/` (which is not treated as a word-character) – because e.g. `\</` basically says "match the beginning of a word directly followed by something other than a word (a 'slash', in this case)", which is impossible.

**What will work**

This will match `/` surrounded by whitespace (`\s`) or beginning/end of line:

```
egrep '(^|\s)/($|\s)' file
```

(`egrep` implies the `-E` option, which turns on processing of *extended regular expressions*.)

**What might also work**

The following slightly simpler expression will work if a `/` is never adjacent to non-word characters (such as `*`, `#`, `-`, and characters outside the ASCII range); it might be of limited usefulness in OP's case:

```
grep '\B/\B' file
```

Comment: it does work, but unfortunatelly it also match "//" or "///", so it grep not only one "slash" but also many of them in a row

Answer (score 2):

```
for str in  'some text / pictures' ' /home ' '/ text' ' text /'; do
  echo "$str" | egrep '(^|\s)/($|\s)'
done
```

This will match `/`:

- if the *entire input string* is `/`
- if the input string *starts with* `/` and is followed by at least 1 whitespace
- if the input string *ends with* `/` and is preceded by at least 1 whitespace
- if `/` is *inside* the input string surrounded by at least 1 whitespace on *either* side.

---

As for why `grep "\</\>" file` did not work:

`\<` and `/>` match the left/right boundaries between *words* and *non-words*. However, **`/` does not qualify as a *word***, because words are defined as a sequence of one or more instances of characters from the set `[[:alnum:]_]`, i.e.: sequences of at least length 1 composed entirely of *letters*, *digits*, or `_`.

Answer (score -3):

This seems to work for me.

```
grep -rni " / \| /\|/ " .
```

Comment: Incorrect: will not match a line consisting of only `/`